# Javascript if variable is undefined then use another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two scopes `$scope.job` and `$scope.jobs`

I have `var job;`

If `$scope.job` is `undefined` I would like `$scope.jobs` to work under `job` so it would be `var job = $scope.jobs` but if `$scope.job` is defined I want to write it to that variable too.

```
if ( $scope.job ) {
    var job = $scope.job; 
} else {
    var job = $scope.jobs; 
}
```

But in shorthand

Comment: ```var job = $scope.job || $scope.jobs;```

Comment: `var job = $scope.job || $scope.jobs`

Comment: *"I want to write it to that variable too."* -- As in you want to write to *both* variables? Currently you are writing to one.

Comment: `var job = $scope.job = $scope.job || $scope.jobs;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to leave short comment but now I understand that will be better if I explain.

```
var job = $scope.job || $scope.jobs;
```

`undefined == false; // prints true`

So that's how it works.

```
If $scope.job == undefined == false || $scope.jobs == {...} == true.
```

If job will be undefined - it will be false so `or` operand returns true value.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand what you mean:

```
if ($scope.job)
  var job = $scope.job;
else
{
  var job = $scope.jobs;
  $scope.job = $scope.jobs;
}
```

well, shorthand then:

```
var job = $scope.job = $scope.job || $scope.jobs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use ternary operator

```
var job = $scope.job ? $scope.job : $scope.jobs
```

or

```
var job = $scope.job == undefined ? $scope.job : $scope.jobs
```